# Bisimulations: Proof that the following LTS are not bisimilar

Tags: coinduction

I have the two LTS (labeled transition system) as seen in the following picture:
[image]
And the book is telling me that between those two LTS, their $1$ and $1'$ are non-bisimilar.

So I tried to get a bisimilation starting from the pair $\{\{1,1'\}\}$ by continuously extending it whenever I found a conflict, ending up with:
$$\{   \{1,1'\} ,\{2,2'\},\{3,3'\},\{2,4'\},\{4,3'\},\{3,5'\},\{4,5'\}               \}$$

Finally, to check whether it truly was a bisimilation, I checked for each pair each node, and asserted that all possible pairs of derivatives were part of the set.

I am arriving that they are a bisimilation - is the crux in the $a$'s and $b$'s? 
(They didn't really explain what it means)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left diagram has a b and the right diagram has a c.  Thus, the pair $(2,4')$ does not satisfy the conditions required to be a bisimulation.  In particular, the book is correct that those two systems are not bisimilar.

Comment: So, in conclusion, it is irrelevant that we have parallel branches with the same action (e.g. $a$), but it is relevant for a bisimulation that ... the actions taken, i.e. $a,b,c$,  are the same?

Comment: @Sudix, I didn't try to work that out; I am merely answering the question, for the specific example you gave.  If you are wondering about what would happen if you replaced a c with a b in the right-hand picture, I suggest you spend some time working through the details.  Checking whether the conditions of the definition hold is a mechanical process that you should be able to do as well as i can.